# pyshphere method for login into vm instance on ESX server

Tags: python

I am having a difficulties to login on VM hosted on esx server.

```
>>> from pysphere import VIServer
>>> server = VIServer()
>>> server.connect("192.168.1.10", "root", "abc123")
>>> vmlist = server.get_registered_vms()
>>> vm1 = server.get_vm_by_name("Windows 7")
>>> vm1.login_in_guest(“user”, "test1234")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysphere/vi_virtual_machine.py", line 1027, in   login_in_guest
self.__validate_authentication(auth)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pysphere/vi_virtual_machine.py", line 1706, in __validate_authentication
raise VIApiException(e)
pysphere.resources.vi_exception.VIApiException: [GuestOperationsUnavailableFault]: The guest operations agent could not be contacted.
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that VMware tools needs to be installed on the VM before the login attempt. Did you install tools on the VM?

The error message you posted strongly suggests that tools isn't running inside your guest.